# Search input on Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress

On a custom post type, I have filters that display content based on taxonomies, year, and language. I want to add a search field that will work in conjunction with the other filters. Can someone help me with this?

```
function get_bp_results() {

    $company = clean_field('bp-company');
    $year = clean_field('bp-year');
    $languages = clean_field('bp-languages');
    $keywords = get_keywords_array();

    $tax_query = $date_query = $post_types = [];

    $all_langs = !empty($languages) && $languages == '1';

    if (!empty($year)) {
        $date_query[] = [
            'year' => $year,
        ];
    }

    if (!empty($company)) {
        $tax_query[] = [
            'taxonomy'  => 'company',
            'field'     => 'term_id',
            'terms'     => $company
        ];
    }

    if (!empty($keywords)) {
        foreach ($keywords as $kw) {
            $tax_query[] = [
                'taxonomy'  => 'keywords',
                'field'     => 'term_id',
                'terms'     => $kw
            ];
        }
    }

    if ($all_langs) {
        foreach (get_option('lexoseo__langs') as $key => $value) {
            $post_types[] = "cpt-bestpractices-{$key}";
        }
    } else {
        $post_types[] = "cpt-bestpractices-{$_SESSION['jez']}";
    }

    $args = [
        'numberposts'       => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'menu_order',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'post_type'         => $post_types,
        'suppress_filters'  => true,
        'tax_query'         => $tax_query,
        'date_query'        => $date_query,
    ];

    $results = new WP_Query($args);

    ob_start();

    if ($results->have_posts()) { ?>
        <div id="bp-results">
            <?php while ($results->have_posts()) {
                
                $results->the_post();

                $bp_post = get_post();

                
                
                
                get_template_part('template-parts/bp-block', null, [
                    'bp_post' => $bp_post,
                    'new_tab' => true
                ]);
            } ?>

    </div>     
        </div>



        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="no-bp-results">
            <h3><?php echo __lt('frontend', 'no_bp_results', $_SESSION['jez']); ?></h3>
        </div>
    <?php }

    if (wp_doing_ajax()) {
        wp_send_json_success([
            'message' => handle_manual_hyphenation(ob_get_clean())
        ]);
    } else {
        return handle_manual_hyphenation(ob_get_clean());
    }
}
```

I try to create some function, but after that search work but other filter doesn't work.

```
function fetch_ajax() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', query: jQuery('#search').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#bp-results-inner').html( data );
        }
    });
}
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'fetch_ajax' );

function data_fetch(){
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => $_POST['query'], 'post_type' => array('cpt-bestpractices-en','cpt-bestpractices-de') ) );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :?>
    <div id="bp-results">

      <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); 

      ?>
           
            <?php get_template_part('template-parts/bp-block')?>
            
       
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
       <?php wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- Try to paste this code in functions.php

function custom_post_type_search_filter($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive('custom_post_type')) {
        // Check if the search query parameter is present
        $search_query = get_query_var('s');
        
        // Check if other filter parameters are present
        $taxonomy_filter = get_query_var('taxonomy');
        $year_filter = get_query_var('year');
        $language_filter = get_query_var('language');

        // Modify the main query based on the filters
        if ($search_query) {
            $query->set('s', $search_query);
        }
        
        if ($taxonomy_filter) {
            $query->set('tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $taxonomy_filter,
                ),
            ));
        }
        
        if ($year_filter) {
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'year',
                    'value'   => $year_filter,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ));
        }
        
        if ($language_filter) {
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'language',
                    'value'   => $language_filter,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ));
        }
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_search_filter');
```

'cpt-bestpractices-en','cpt-bestpractices-de' - replace this custom post type in this function.